# method in express js get() - returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this Node.js code that should, using Express.js http get, decode my jwt token from my http auth header.

When I write the code of `decodeToken()` inside of my express js `get()` method, everything works fine.

When I extract it to outside method (`decodeToken()` method) I get that `undefined` value from this method. Mind you, when this code was hard coded inside of the method `get()` it works.

Why is that, the async nature of Node.js? Does the method finish after the `get()` method was supposed to assign the token?

If I will use promises, will it solve that?

```
var jwtCheck = expressJwt({
        secret: "some secret"

});

app.use('/test', jwtCheck);

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {

    var token = req.get('Authorization').split("Bearer ")[1];

    var information = decodeToken(token)
    console.log("information: "+information);
    if (information!=null) {
        res.json(information);
    }
    else {
        res.json('Failed to authenticate token.');
    }
});

var decodeToken = function (token) {
       console.log(token);
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to authenticate token.');
            return null;
        } else {

            return (decoded);
        }
    });
}

var getToken = function (req) {
    return req.get('Authorization').split("Bearer ")[1];
}
```

Comment: One thing I can see is that `secret` passed to `jwt.verify` is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jwt.verify` is async because you pass a callback to it so anything that calls it needs to handle that. You could look at promises to clean up the logic a little bit but just using the code you have you could modify it like this:

```
var jwtCheck = expressJwt({
        secret: "some secret"

});

app.use('/test', jwtCheck);

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {

    var token = req.get('Authorization').split("Bearer ")[1];

    // pass callback to decodeToken that gets called after the token is verified
    decodeToken(token, function(information) {
      // this function won't execute until decodeToke calls it as `next()`
      console.log("information: "+information);
      if (information!=null) {
          res.json(information);
      }
      else {
          res.json('Failed to authenticate token.');
      }
    })
});

// accept `next` callback
var decodeToken = function (token, next) {
    console.log(token);
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to authenticate token.');
            return next(null);
        } else {

            return next(decoded);
        }
    });
}

var getToken = function (req) {
    return req.get('Authorization').split("Bearer ")[1];
}
```